# stackoverflow error while checkout and compare

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, arraylist, jprofiler

receiving stackoverflow error:
Operation: We are trying to compare xml's  (checkedout from repo)and we are using arraylist and hashmaps to perform node by node comparison, but somewhere in the process i am receiving this error. I checked, there are no infiniteloop and there is no concurrent modification. not sure where exactly its throwing this error. Also, one point i observed is temp folder is used for our xml checkout, sometimes the size of temp folder grows to around 600mb because of refreence xmls within main xml, as those reference xmls are also checkedout for comparison.

I have checked for npe's also.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:314)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.access$000(URLClassPath.java:60)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:195)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:206)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:416)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:413)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:438)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
```

Comment: Provide the code causing the error

Comment: We try to loop thru all the tree hierarchy and add one node after another into hashmap and then later convert it to tree, pardon me as code is lot more to be pasted here

Comment: trying to utilize evaluation version of JProfiler to see any hotspot

Comment: There could be a million causes of this. Maybe a recursive call gets stuck between two or more XML elements that are linked to each other with an attribute? Maybe maybe maybe maybe. Provide some context. This is not a real question.

Comment: Ok, how to approach these kind of StackOverFlow errors where in we do not see any thing pointing to our code. I mean to say is, I do not see any of our code (com.vogella.performance.compare) in the stack trace. 

As mentioned above, the stack trace just points to arraylist and then some classLoader:

     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
     at rg.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)